# ManyToMany relationship not persisting in JPA when adding a new one

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, persist

I have this piece of code which adds an entry to `film_actor` (in theory), but it doesn't work. This code doesn't crash, but doesn't save the added entry to the database.

```
    Actor nuevo = ActorFacadeEJB.find(actor_id);
    Film pelicula = FilmFacadeEJB.find(film_id);

    pelicula.getActors().add(nuevo);
```

Also I have this code:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "film_actor", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "film_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "actor_id") })   
    private Set<Actor> actors;


    public Set<Actor> getActors() {
        return actors;
    }
```

The actor also has a film set:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="actors")
private Set<Film> film= new HashSet<Film>();
```

How can I fix all this to make it work? I googled it, and many people have similar code to mine, but just mine doesn't work.

Comment: Is there an Actor collection in the Film class?

Comment: Yes, it's the private Set<Actor> actors; it's in the code above

Comment: And the Actor class has a Film collection?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question and added the code

Comment: Are you in a transaction?  You are changing the Film entity, but changes are only picked up if the entity is managed (read from a context associated to a transaction) and the transaction commits.  Otherwise your FilmFacadeEJB will need a save method so that your change can be merged into a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

```
Make sure your Annotations are proper as below :
@Entity
@Table(name="film")
class Film{
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name="film_actor", 
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="film_id")}, 
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="actor_id")})
 private Set<Actor> actors=new HashSet<Actor>;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="actor")
class Actor{
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="actors")
    private Set<Film> film= new HashSet<Film>();
}
```

Comment: I wrote my code like this now (identical) but still doesn't work. It doesn't crash either though.

Comment: By the way, when adding to the Set, should I also execute another method so the changes are saved? or does it save automatically when I .add() to the Set?

Comment: pls check if you are giving exact names of Table in annotations, also save it after you have added to the Set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign both sides of the relationship:

```
pelicula.getActors().add(nuevo);
nuevo.getFilms().add(película);
```